# Semidirect product of semidirect products

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

For algebraic objects, say for groups $ N,K$ and algebra $A$, if we have the semidirect product of a semidirect product, 
$(A \rtimes_{\gamma} N ) \rtimes_{\theta} K$, are there conditions that would allow us to collapse this to a single semidirect product over $A$?

Comment: I can think of some very trivial conditions which probably don't interest you. Probably if you say more about your situation you can get better answers.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/156209/iterated-semi-direct-products